# How to find sum of rows based of condition

Tags: algorithm, sqlite

I have following table:

```
ID Minutes Flag
-- ------- ---- 
A    8      0
A    9      0
A    21     0
A    5      0
B    32     0
B    21     0
```

and I have to create a table as below

```
ID Minutes Flag
-- ------- ---- 
A    8      0
A    9      0
A    21     1
A    5      0
B    32     1
B    21     0
```

basically I have iterate over given table and update flag when sum of minutes reaches 30 or more and then reset sum(have to find a way to store sum) to 0 and start over again till sum reaches 30 or more

Sum should also reset if ID changes (i.e A to B)

Condition: I have to use SQLite

Comment: Although you can do this with a recursive CTE, this is one type of operation that is reasonable to perform with a loop in the application.

Comment: In SQL, table rows are unsorted. Is there a timestamp or someother column that allows sorting?

Comment: Yes my data is sorted based on Id and TimeStamp, I am getting minutes as a difference of two consecutive row value

This I have done in a step previous to it